# Store a value in redis store using Nestjs

Tags: redis, nestjs

I have a simple nestjs application, where I have set up a `CacheModule` using `Redis` store as follows:

```js
import * as redisStore from 'cache-manager-redis-store';

CacheModule.register({
      store: redisStore,
      host: 'redis',
      port: 6379,
    }),
```

I would like to use it to store a single value, however, I do not want to do it the built-in way by attaching an interceptor to a controller method, but instead I want to control it manually and be able to set and retrieve the value in the code.

How would I go about doing that and would I even use cache manager for that?

Comment: If you want to use redis with your nest application, its better to use redis module already provided by someone. This module has a service through which you can set and get aything you want into your redis.
[nestjs-redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-redis)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on Ahmad's comment above, I used the following to enable redis in my nestjs application:

1. Install and setup `nestjs-redis` https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-redis per docs.
2. See the docs here on how to write and read values in a Redis store:
   https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis

Comment: The project looks abandoned and it is not compatible with NestJS 8+.

Comment: `nestjs-redis` uses `ioredis` behind the scene and not the `node-redis` module!

Answer (score 17):

You can use the official way from Nest.js:

### 1. Create your RedisCacheModule:

#### 1.1. `redisCache.module.ts`:

```js
import { Module, CacheModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import * as redisStore from 'cache-manager-redis-store';
import { RedisCacheService } from './redisCache.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    CacheModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        store: redisStore,
        host: configService.get('REDIS_HOST'),
        port: configService.get('REDIS_PORT'),
        ttl: configService.get('CACHE_TTL'),
      }),
    }),
  ],
  providers: [RedisCacheService],
  exports: [RedisCacheService] // This is IMPORTANT,  you need to export RedisCacheService here so that other modules can use it
})
export class RedisCacheModule {}
```

#### 1.2. `redisCache.service.ts`:

```js
import { Injectable, Inject, CACHE_MANAGER } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';

@Injectable()
export class RedisCacheService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private readonly cache: Cache,
  ) {}

  async get(key) {
    await this.cache.get(key);
  }

  async set(key, value) {
    await this.cache.set(key, value);
  }
}
```

### 2. Inject RedisCacheModule wherever you need it:

Let's just assume we will use it in module `DailyReportModule`:

#### 2.1. `dailyReport.module.ts`:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RedisCacheModule } from '../cache/redisCache.module';
import { DailyReportService } from './dailyReport.service';

@Module({
  imports: [RedisCacheModule],
  providers: [DailyReportService],
})
export class DailyReportModule {}
```

#### 2.2. `dailyReport.service.ts`:

We will use the `redisCacheService` here:

```js
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cron } from '@nestjs/schedule';
import { RedisCacheService } from '../cache/redisCache.service';

@Injectable()
export class DailyReportService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(DailyReportService.name);

  constructor(
    private readonly redisCacheService: RedisCacheService, // REMEMBER TO INJECT THIS
  ) {}

  @Cron('0 1 0 * * *') // Run cron job at 00:01:00 everyday
  async handleCacheDailyReport() {
    this.logger.debug('Handle cache to Redis');
  }
}
```

You can check my sample code [here](https://github.com/piavgh/nestjs-order-management/blob/main/src/cache/redisCache.module.ts).

Comment: I am getting error after installing.
 Could not find a declaration file for module 'cache-manager-redis-store'

Comment: @har17bar npm install cache-manager-redis-store   should do the trick for you

Answer (score 0):

If you're connection a external Redis, I recommend to use 'async-redis' package.

The code will be:

```
import * as redis from 'async-redis';
import redisConfig from '../../config/redis';
```

On redisConfig:

```
export default {
   host: 'your Host',
   port: parseInt('Your Port Conection'),
   // Put the first value in hours
   // Time to expire a data on redis
   expire: 1 * 60 * 60,
   auth_pass: 'password',
};
```

So, you run:

```
var dbConnection = redis.createClient(config.db.port, config.db.host, 
{no_ready_check: true});
```

Now you can, execute commands like set and get for your Redis Database.

Comment: I am getting error after installing. Could not find a declaration file for module 'cache-manager-redis-store'

Comment: @har17bar try to install this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cache-manager-redis-store